# SIPP uas.xml and uac.xml

Tags: xml, sip

I have to change the uas.xml and uac.xml in SIPP such that it will support returning 2 headers or 2 via's .
For example :

```
  ACK sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port] SIP/2.0
  Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port]
  **Via: STACKOVERFLOW** 
  From: sipp <sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]>
  To: sut <sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port]>
  Call-ID: [call_id]
  CSeq: 1 ACK
  Contact: sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]
  Max-Forwards: 70
  Subject: Performance Test
  Content-Length: 0

]]>
```

In order to that, i have to change the text in the <[CDATA]> ( in the xml files) but i don't know any idea how to do that.
 what's the change i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your uac and uas will communicate directly (no intermediate proxies or application servers): Simply add your via-line using hardcoded values:

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.10.67:5060

or using SIPp variables

Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port]

It is also possible to manipulate assign values to local variables ($1, $2 etc) within SIPp script or read from CSV files (field0, field1, ... fieldn) and use them like reserved variables within brackets.

See the reference document: http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second Via line, after the other. For instance:

```
ACK sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port] SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port]
Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [other_ip]:[other_port]
From: sipp <sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]>
To: sut <sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port]>
Call-ID: [call_id]
CSeq: 1 ACK
Contact: sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]
Max-Forwards: 70
Subject: Performance Test
Content-Length: 0

]]>
```